# OS X: Can `ls` show broken symlinks?

Tags: osx, ls, symlink, colors

When in Linux, I enjoy having `\ls -l --color=auto` show **broken symlinks** with red text for the name of the symlink and blinking text for the missing linkee.  But in OS X, `\ls -lG` (the closest thing I can find) displays broken and unbroken symlinks identically.

Does anyone know how to have OS X's `ls` display broken symlinks differently from unbroken ones?  It doesn't have to be the exact same display as Linux, but just something to indicate the broken state.

(If it matters, I also use the `-A` and `-F` options.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately with the current OSX (BSD) `ls` this seems to not be possible. Referring to the man page these are your only options:

```
LSCOLORS    The value of this variable describes what color to use for which
            attribute when colors are enabled with CLICOLOR.  This string is a
            concatenation of pairs of the format fb, where f is the foreground
            color and b is the background color.

            The color designators are as follows:
              a     black
              b     red
              c     green
              d     brown
              e     blue
              f     magenta
              g     cyan
              h     light grey
              A     bold black, usually shows up as dark grey
              B     bold red
              C     bold green
              D     bold brown, usually shows up as yellow
              E     bold blue
              F     bold magenta
              G     bold cyan
              H     bold light grey; looks like bright white
              x     default foreground or background

            Note that the above are standard ANSI colors.  The actual display may
            differ depending on the color capabilities of the terminal in use.

            The order of the attributes are as follows:
              1.   directory
              2.   symbolic link
              3.   socket
              4.   pipe
              5.   executable
              6.   block special
              7.   character special
              8.   executable with setuid bit set
              9.   executable with setgid bit set
              10.  directory writable to others, with sticky bit
              11.  directory writable to others, without sticky bit

            The default is "exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad", i.e. blue foreground and
            default background for regular directories, black foreground and
            red background for setuid executables, etc.
```

So, unless there is some undocumented trick for dealing with other filetypes than this list of 10, then your best option is to install [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) which contains the `ls` you are familiar with where `or` *orphan* allows a color spec for your broken symlinks in the `LSCOLORS` environment variable.

Comment: Didn't know about Coreutils, which is the solution I went with.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: For those switching to coreutils (gnu) ls: there is a good documentation on setting up LSCOLORS [here](http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html).